# PagerSlidingTabStrip - add new tab at run time

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am using PagerSlidingTabStrip to show 3 tabs, with each containing list view in it.

I have a scenario where i need to add new tab at runtime, say on swipe to refresh  i need to add new tab to the left end.

Below is my code to add new tab :

```
pagerAdapter.TABS_COUNT = 4; //global value to change the tabs count
pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mPager);
```

but some times one of the tabs content becomes empty listview is not scrollable.

What is the best way that i can achieve this ?

Comment: There's probably some problem with your pager adapter.

Comment: why don't you use fragment pager adapter + fragment inside view pager that will help you to add a fragment to run time in view pager.

Comment: @user2056563 can you post more relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do it, don't say it's the best way, but I wrote it in hurry https://github.com/jacktech24/pager-sliding-strip-example

First, you will need a custom adapter, here I used a simple one which is displaying only text on each fragment, but it would be easy to modify it to support normal fragments etc. mTabs in the example is:

```
mTabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
```

then the example

```
private class TestAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>();

        public TestAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment frag = new ExampleFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", (String) getPageTitle(position));
            frag.setArguments(bundle);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabs.size();
        }

        public void addTab(String tab) {
            tabs.add(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            mTabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void removeTab(int position) {
            tabs.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            mTabs.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

then, it is just as simple as this:

```
    //mAdapter is instance of your adapter
    mAdapter.addTab("test 1");
    mAdapter.addTab("test 2");
    mAdapter.addTab("test 3");


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAdapter.addTab("test "+(mAdapter.getCount()+1));
        }
    });
```